# How to remove legend in ant-design donut chart

Tags: reactjs, charts, components, antd, donut-chart

I don't want legend in my donut chart in @ant-design/plots.

I have tried passing `legend:false` in the statistic of chart config.

```
const config = {
    appendPadding: 10,
    data,
    angleField: 'value',
    colorField: 'type',
    radius: 1,
    innerRadius: 0.6,
    label: {
      type: 'inner',
      offset: '-50%',
      content: '{value}',
      style: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontSize: 14,
      },
    },
    interactions: [
      {
        type: 'element-selected',
      },
      {
        type: 'element-active',
      },
    ],
    statistic: {
      title: false,
      legend:false,
      content: {
        style: {
          whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap',
          overflow: 'hidden',
          textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
        },
        content: 'AntV\nG2Plot',
      },
    },
  };
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Move legend:false to config object

You should use `legend:false` directly inside the config object rather than inside the statistic object.

The below code would remove the legend from the donut chart as needed.

```
const config = {
    legend:false,
    appendPadding: 10,
    data,
    angleField: 'value',
    colorField: 'type',
    radius: 1,
    innerRadius: 0.6,
    label: {
      type: 'inner',
      offset: '-50%',
      content: '{value}',
      style: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontSize: 14,
      },
    },
    interactions: [
      {
        type: 'element-selected',
      },
      {
        type: 'element-active',
      },
    ],
    statistic: {
      title: false,
      content: {
        style: {
          whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap',
          overflow: 'hidden',
          textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
        },
        content: 'AntV\nG2Plot',
      },
    },
  };
```

Comment: how do i change the position of the legend? instead of it being on the side, i want it at the top

Comment: @tonybaidoo You can add `legend: { layout: 'horizontal', position: 'top' },` For more details check the docs here https://charts.ant.design/en/api/plots/pie